# Naming windows in hstack openCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am using open-CV - 2.4 with python-3. I am able to show multiple images at the same time (8 of them and, I don't want to reduce the number). But many times, these windows overlap each other. So, I want to be able to put them all in the same windowj.

So, to do this I used the function `np.hstack()`. Now, my problem is that I don't know how to show their names(i.e I would like to give the names to these windows individually, the way we do using `cv2.imshow("name", window)` ).

Also, I want to avoid using GUI libraries like tkinter and qt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you stack all the images into one, and show it, then there's just 1 window to give a name to, not 8. What you could do is use the OpenCV drawing functions to draw text directly onto the combined image.

Comment: Okay! I can do that. I did have something like that in mind, but was looking for a more systematic way because I do have a loooot  of text going on to the window.